# PowerShell New-ADUser Multiple Variables for AccountPassword

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have 50+ Active Directory users to create and I am attempting to do so with PowerShell. The idea is to have the username contain a number and increment by one through the loop. I'm also attempting to do the same increment with the password. The following script works with the exception of the password. I cannot figure out how to get the password to work.

The ideal result will be the users will be created like this...

Username: Training1
Password: Training1#5076

Username: Training2
Password: Training2#5076

etc, etc, etc,.

```
[string]$FirstName = "Training"
[string]$Pwd1 = "Training"
[string]$Pwd2 = "#5076"
[int]$repeat = 1 #Change this to 50

for ($counter = 1; $counter -le $repeat; $counter++){
    $FnCount = "$FirstName$counter"    
    $PwdCount = ConvertTo-SecureString $Pwd1$counter$Pwd2 -AsPlainText -Force
    $UserPath = "OU=Training,OU=ABC_Users,DC=ABC,DC=local"
    $GroupPath = "OU=ABC_Groups,DC=ABC,DC=local"
    $Pword = "ThisIsAPassword1!"
    $Groups = @("Training","Remote")

    $UserObject = @{
        AccountPassword = $PwdCount
        Name = $FnCount
        GivenName = $FnCount
        PasswordNeverExpires = $True
        Path = $UserPath
        SamAccountname = $FnCount
        UserPrincipalName = "$FnCount@ABC.local"   
        Enabled = $True
        DisplayName = $FnCount
        CannotChangePassword = $True
    }

    New-ADUser @UserObject
    
    #Add account to groups
    Get-ADGroup -Server "abc.local" -SearchBase $GroupPath -Filter "name -like 'Training'" | Add-ADGroupMember -Members "CN=$Name,$UserPath"
    Get-ADGroup -Server "abc.local" -SearchBase $GroupPath -Filter "name -like 'Remote'" | Add-ADGroupMember -Members "CN=$Name,$UserPath"
}
```

I have tried entering a simple string for the $PwCount and it works. I have tried using a variable for $PwCount and it works. Where things break, is when I try to use multiple varialbes, in this case, including the $counter. Each time I attempt to run the script, I receive error: Cannot bind parameter 'AccountPassword'. Cannot convert the "System.Security.SecureString" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString".

Comment: Try quoting the combined password `"$Pwd1$counter$Pwd2"` or use the [-f Format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#format-operator--f) like `('{0}{1}{2}' -f $Pwd1, $counter, $Pwd2)`

Answer (score 0):

As someone already commented, you can replace the `$PwdCount` variable to something like this `$PwdCount = ConvertTo-SecureString ("{0}{1}{2}" -f $Pwd1, $counter, $Pwd2) -AsPlainText -Force`. But, I just wanted to mention, if the first part of `$PwdCount` is just `$FnCount`, why not just have the `$PwdCount` string to be `$FnCount$Pwd2`? Anyways, here's what I came up with:

```
[string]$train = "Training"
[string]$pwd = "#5076"
[int]$start = 1
[int]$end = 10

$start..$end | foreach {
    $FnCount = "$train$_"
    $PwdCount = ConvertTo-SecureString "$FnCount$pwd" -AsPlainText -Force
    ...
```